# When I set the textfield to the next line in Flutter, the text goes up

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I want to get rid of the letters going up when I hit enter in a text field. What should I do?

[image]

It's part of the code.

```dart
Container(
                          child: TextField(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            autofocus: true,
                            // controller: myController,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              // print('$value');
                              setState(() {
                                mainText = value;
                              });
                            },
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                            minLines: 1,
                            maxLines: 10,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: "짧은 글귀를 집필해주세요",
                              hintStyle:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
```

Comment: You want to typed text in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your hint text you just want short text and you can achieve by integrating with only single line textfield

```
  Container(
      child: TextField(
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        autofocus: true,
        // controller: myController,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            mainText = value;
          });
        },
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text, // this is change
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done, // this is change
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: "짧은 글귀를 집필해주세요",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

for multiline text:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
maxLines: 5,
textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
```

Comment: I solved the problem with difficulty. I wanted to fix the phenomenon that the whole thing goes up when I press enter. I didn't want it to be just one line. But thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your textfield with a Container. And set the container height.

Then in your textfield set `expands:true`

Now, your text won't goes up when pressing enter

```
Container(
        height: 250,   // set the height
        child: TextField(
        expands: true, // set the expands to true
        maxLines: null)
               
         ),
```

Answer (score 0):

`keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,`

`maxLines: 7,`

`minLines: 1,`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**